# How do I add a simple mouseover info window

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to add a simple mouse over info window to a bar chart to give the user the ability to look at the exact data. How would I add that to this d3 bar chart?

Here is the Plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/d0ReUGwk4l066yuMZYXw?p=preview

I thought I could add something like this but I was getting errors

```
bars.attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.state);
})
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("width", function(d) {
        return x();
    })
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return color(i);
    })
    .attr("id", function(d, i) {
        return i;
    })
    .on("mouseover", function() {
        d3.select(this)
            .attr("fill", "red");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d, i) {
        d3.select(this).attr("fill", function() {
            return "" + color(this.id) + "";
        });
    });

bars.append("title")
    .text(function(d) {
        return "";
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is as follows:

Add a tooltip `div` element which you will default to being invisible and can be programmatically update via d3 with data and to make it visible during mouseover events.

```
<style>
#tooltip {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.92);
  position:absolute;
  height:auto;
  visibility:hidden;
  z-index:9999;
  padding:5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
</style>
<div id="tooltip">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="series">y</div>
  </div>
  <span>X: </span><span id="xval"></span><br/>
  <span>Y: </span><span id="yval"></span>
</div>
```

Later on, you add this to your `rect` elements that represent the bars. This should be fairly self-explanatory. Feel free to leave a comment if you are unclear on any of the steps:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    d3.select("#tooltip")
      .style("left", x1(d.key) + x0(d.state) + "px")
      .style("top", y(d.value) - 50 + "px")
      .transition()
      .style("visibility", "visible");
    d3.select("#series")
      .text(d.key);
    d3.select('#xval')
      .text(d.state);
    d3.select("#yval")
      .text(d3.format("0.6")(d.value));
});
```

Note that I also changed your data loop to make sure that the state value is also stored for each `rect` element so you can easily pull it out for the tooltip.

Here is a working version:

https://plnkr.co/edit/EoJbTgmRZ1VXTtmfLd9A?p=preview

PS - I'd highly recommend learning to roll your own tooltip for now. There is probably a library for everything you ever need, but tooltips are fairly straighforward to implement and doing so helps you improve your basic understanding of working with d3 and javascript to make interactive visualizations. Moreover, if you roll your own, you have the flexibility and confidence to make custom types of tooltips that might better serve your requirements than trying to use a library with limited customization options.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It was very helpful. I'm learning on the fly with HTML, JS, and D3 right now, so my knowledge is lacking. I'm making an effort to read up on creating my own tooltips with your suggestion and d3/html in general.

Comment: You're very welcome. All the best with learning HTML/JS/D3. It's a lot of fun!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know very well d3.js but this page explain how add tooltips to a d3 bar chart : http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579

Hoping it's will help you.